# Why Override option removed from Configure Vector Asset in Android Studio 3.5?

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable, android-studio-3.5

I import SVG file for vector drawable in Android Studio.

There were an Options for **Override** vector drawable.

[image: Before Android studio 3.5]
After update android studio to 3.5. Override option is not available. 
[image: In Android studio 3.5 version]
**So is there any way to re-enable this?**

Comment: Did you find solution for this issue?

Comment: Noup, I didn't find a solution.

Comment: This is so weird. Thanks for your response